# DatePicker for ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5

I need a datepicker but not the usual one, for example, of bootsrap. This one only allows me to pick a specific date and what I need in terms of visual is the same, but I want to get me:

- Begin and End date (to give me a date interval);
- Get the info about the current month is showing;

Is there any alternatives to that bootstrap calendar?

Edit: Like the MonthCalendar on WindowsForms

Comment: http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I need

Answer (score 0):

> you can use jquery ui datepicker plugins to bootstrap datepicker
>   alternatives, and jquery ui datepicker support in more browser than
>   bootrap